# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing on using input and raw_input

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, eof

I am currently making a fun password cracking game which shows you what the process of brute force cracking is and how it works. Secretly it's just something to impress the IT Department as my school, but that's besides the point. I am only at the beginning of the program's development and I have already run into an error, and a pretty common error at that. If it's common, why can I not find a fix for it I here you ask. Well, most threads are to out-dated or don't cater for my specific situation.

Here is the piece of code which is causing me the problem:

```
while beginning_input == ' ':
    ("Please select which difficulty you would like the password to be > ")
    beginning_input = raw_input
    if beginning_input != ("EASY", "MEDIUM", "HARD"):
```

Line 1 and 4 are not relevant but still, threw them in there. In the basic of it I am trying to ask the person who is running this what they want the difficulty of the password to be... but I get this error once I run this code in Command Prompt.

```
  File "passwordcrackinggame.py", line 8
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Any help with fixing this problem would be greatly appreciated, thank you. Need any information? Dont moan, just ask me.

Comment: Please fix you indentation. Especially with a language like Python, to us, poor indentation hides the real problem.

Comment: You never called this function `beginning_input = raw_input` you just assigned the function `raw_input` object to a variable, you probably meant `beginning_input = raw_input()`

Comment: why is it not `beginning_input = raw_input("Please select which difficulty you would like the password to be (Easy, Medium, Hard).`

Comment: @JakeSteele Not dumb... Did you know it gives the same effect if I did it my way or not?

Comment: @CoryKramer Aha, dumb me, sorry. I will try that.

Comment: @CoryKramer Gives the same output.

Comment: First of all python3 doesn't have `raw_input`, only `input`. I think you're using python2.

Comment: @Carcigenicate People like me need explanation, I will 'fix' my indentation and see if it even makes any difference.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Actually, for some reason, it formatted weird when I put my code in. My code looks different, its the same as in the post but the while line is touching the left side like its supposed to.

Comment: @BenColligan You're probably mixing spaces and tabs, which looks weird when pasted. And I meant the indentation of the code posted here. I'm assuming your actual code is formated correctly. If it looked as you posted it here, it would never run. Everything under the "while" needs to be indented.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is in the wrong order.

### `raw_input` is a function

You need to call

```
raw_input(textToShowTheUser)
```

which in your case
would be

```
raw_input("Please select which difficulty you would like the password to be > ")
```

### `(A, B, C)` is a tuple

You're doing this

```
if beginning_input != ("EASY", "MEDIUM", "HARD"):
```

but this is only true when `beggining_input`is `("EASY", "MEDIUM", "HARD")`. It's a tuple literal, not an easy way to compare multiple values.

If you wanted to check if one is **in** the other, you would use the `in` operator, and since you want to check that it's *not* in the tuple, you'll want to negate the result with a `not` operator.

```
if not beginning_input in ("EASY", "MEDIUM", "HARD"):
```

### Indentation

I know this was a typo, but the indentation must be exact. Combining everything above, this is what the final code should look like.

```
begginning_input = " "
while beginning_input == ' ':
     beginning_input = raw_input("Please select which difficulty you would like the password to be > ")
     if not beginning_input in ("EASY", "MEDIUM", "HARD"):
```

Comment: Ironic, he could save others from poor indentation, but not himself

Comment: @Cosine Whoops!

Comment: @Max Thanks for clearing it up, dont get how people just down-vote just because I dont understand one thing :/

Comment: @Max Buttttt, its still not fixed for some odd reason.

Comment: Ben Colligan, that would be because you posted code riddled with errors in the original and presentation, mislabeled it with the wrong version of programming language, provided an error that references a line number without pointing out (or even I think knowing) which line number it corresponds to in your code, *and then fought with people when they tried to help*.

Comment: Holy crap, why are you so aggressive about it? Why do you feel the need to write an essay on it? Nice way to be friendly to new people wanting to get into programming.

Comment: @BenColligan But at the very least, a *different* error message should appear. Which error message do you see? :)

Comment: I unfortunately still see the same error. Let me me paste all my code and could you check it for me? I suck. :P

Comment: You don't suck! :)